# Can I permanently cap an unused drain line stub out?

Tags: drain, sewer, abs

I'm building a bathroom in my basement and the builder left a roughed in 1.5" ABS line for the sink. It's a vertical pipe that goes from the roof (presumably) down into the concrete and has a T with a foot-long horizontal run/stub off to the side that's capped with a soft orange cap. However, I don't plan on using this run because the sink will actually go on the other side of the vertical pipe. So my plan is to simply permanently cap this short run with a cemented cap and leave it inside the wall, while splicing in another T above it that points the opposite way. The unused run would then become an appendix of sorts.

Are there any issues or concerns with doing this? Like, could accumulating gas or waste in there cause any problems?

Comment: you know what happens to appendix ?

Comment: @Ruskes intimately familiar, having had an appendectomy as a teenager. Hence me asking here first :)

Comment: If going to add another tee, why not just remove the old tee and put the new tee there?

Comment: @crip659 I'd have to glue in extra pieces, since the pipe would no longer be long enough  to fit inside the T. So it's definitely possible, just extra work. If leaving the old T is a bad idea then that's what I'll end up doing.

Comment: it would become a dead trap, make it useful and turn it in to plunger access port with screw. on cap

Comment: you have newer done this before. The vertical line is a must have vent (true the roof), that allow the drain line to work.

Comment: @Ruskes yes, I understand that the vertical is a vent. I don't plan on doing anything to it, just capping off the short horizontal run that branches off.
I don't think I need a cleanout port because I already have one a couple inches below it.

Comment: Since the horizontal is already presumably pitched slightly down toward the vertical, it shouldn't accumulate any liquid or anything. You or a future owner might change your mind about its usefulness, so as long as a permanent cap can be cut off to add something there in the future you should be fine.